# Как использовать overlay в firefox?

Tags: firefox, overflow

Как использовать overlay в firefox?

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Не использовать overlay, а использовать [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter) например?

Answer (score 0):

```
С этими условиями вы можете избежать выполнения кода в Firefox и Safari.
    И,как результат, использовать значение свойства overflow -- OVERLAY, 
         которое нет возможности использовать для Firefox и Safri.
            И простите за слишком короткий вопрос. Но именно так задают 
                вопросы вновь прибывшие, такие как я).
Overflow: overlay позволяет избежать смещения страницы на ширину скролла, 
   при открытии модальных окон, резервируя пространство под скролл, 
        независимо от его отображения.
                                         Спасибо за внимание!


if (navigator.userAgent.match('Firefox') ||
    (/Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple 
Computer/.test(navigator.vendor))) {
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
} else {
document.body.style.overflow = 'overlay';
}
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите